# Why does range is 'reversed' when filtering objects?

Tags: django, filter, range, django-queryset

I've got a car database and I show "similar cars" on each car's page.

To sort the similar cars, I'm going through this filter:

```
min_power = int(float(car.power_ps) * .8)
max_power = int(float(car.power_ps) * 1.2)

similar_cars = Car.objects.filter(power_ps__range=(min_power, max_power))
```

This mostly works. However, similar cars don't show up on some cars' pages.

When I tweaked my code a bit, I figured that If I use `power_kw` (another power unit and model field) instead of `power_ps` in my queryset, similar cars successfully show up on those pages. But this time, they don't show up on some other cars' pages.

So, I have model instances that:

- don't show similar cars when used `power_ps` but get them with `power_kw`
- don't show similar cars when used `power_kw` but get them with `power_ps`
- don't show similar cars neither when I use `power_ps` nor `power_kw`
- show similar cars either when I use `power_ps` or `power_kw`

When I investigated further, I found out that If I swap the `min_power` and `max_power` in my range filter, similar cars that don't work before show up, **but in the opposite way**; i.e. they show the cars that are out of `min_power`-`max_power` range.

Any suggestion or feedback will be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you use the development server, print out your min and max values, just to see what they are. Also, I think you can increase the Django logging level, which may show you the actual queries send to the database, so you should see the range query with its min and max values as well (this may be another setting than the logging level, you may have to search for that).

Comment: `min_power` and `max_power` values are correct on every page. I will look for logging level, thank you.

Comment: We'd need an example database set and some values of min and max to see how and why things don't match. The current question has too little information, and the mismatches may be simply because relevant items simply don't exist in the database.

Comment: I eventually solved the issue: My Car model's `power_ps` figure was a CharField. That's why when matching the values, Django treated the numbers as text. So for instance 23 was 'bigger' than 123 due to the first digit, and the conflict occured with two digit numbers (`power_ps` < 100). I switched to FloatField and everything works fine now.